# RENDER ERROR: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Tags: react-native

I am learning React Native and I faced this error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object.
```

How can i fix it can you help me?

I'm using this code in Home.js to get the CryptoDetail.js page:

```
onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("CryptoDetail",{currency:item})}
```

I think there is no missing in import and export operations because i did it properly

Comment: Can you please share the full code of the file

Comment: But it's a large file how can i do it?

Comment: Share the content of CryptoDetail.js. It seems that your issues is either having an object in the render() function instead of a component or your definition of CryptoDetail.js is wrong.